# Is there an way to reference a cell inside a url in google sheets?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I'm trying to reference a cell inside a URL and I want to know whether it's possible or not. 
For example, this is my Import Json url.

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

And in A1, I have a value called "AMD".

Is it possible to replace MSFT with AMD by just referencing A1?
What I have in mind is similar to this.

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=A1&apikey=demo

=ImportJSON("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo")

Google Sheets

=ImportJSON("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

=IMPORTJSON("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol="&A1&"&apikey=demo")

[image: Example]